# Is there any way to predefine length of an array parameter by annotations

Tags: java, arrays, annotations

I'm working on a sudoku solving application and i dont want to write a code such as

```
Method(int[] i)
{
   if(i.length == 9)
      {
      // do stuff
      }
   else
      {
      // throw...
      }
}
```

is there any way to enforce arrays parameter to be exact 9 integer by using annotations such as

```
Method(@SizeNine int[] i)
    {
       //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "enforce array parameter to be exact 9" ?

Comment: Nope. But you can simply check it and throw otherwise.

Comment: You can't do it at compile time. Only at runtime as others have mentioned

Comment: You can define a class, e.g. `ArrayWithLength9`, with `get` and `set` methods to access/set the array elements, and enforce the array length in the constructor.

Comment: @Clint i mean int array length should be 9 elements

Comment: The code for size enforcement has to exist somewhere. If it's not in this method, it's in another method.

Comment: @Compass if i construct it this way at first i dont need to check it again

Comment: @AndyTurner i did not understand what you mean

Comment: Basically, the contract for the method is a reference to an array. There is no way to write a contract for a reference to an array of size 9, because that type of reference is not definable without using encapsulation. So you either have to check beforehand, or afterwards.

Comment: You might want to look into AOP.

Comment: I don't understand why people answer "Nope" or "You can't do it at compile time" when they really mean, "_I_ don't know how to do it."

Comment: @mernst i cant agree more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, using a compiler plugin.

Use the [`@ArrayLen`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/common/value/qual/ArrayLen.html) annotation to declare a method whose argument must be a length-9 array of Strings:

```
void myMethod(String @ArrayLen(9) [] a) {
  ...
}
```

Then, compile your program using the [Index Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#index-checker) of the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/manual/):

```
javac -processor index MyJavaFile.java
```

Now, javac will issue a compile-time warning if any client tries to pass an array whose length is not guaranteed to be 9.  If there is a warning, you can fix it and re-compile.  There is no need to perform a run-time check of the array length within your implementation.

Comment: do they have maven plugin or any other easy way to implement?

Comment: The manual gives [instructions for using Maven](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#maven), but there is not a plug-in.

Comment: even though your answer is correct it does not make solution any easier then simply throw an exception actually i was expecting a simple @interface class to solve this problem but thanks anyway you help me alot

Comment: and one more thing if you develop this framework could you please add mutiple dimension support like (String @ArrayLen(9,9) [][] array)

Comment: Each level of the array can be independently annotated.  For example, `String @ArrayLen(9) [] @ArrayLen(9) []`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't enforce it on an *array* (length is not part of the array type in Java, unlike some other languages).

However, you can define a class like this:

```
final class IntArrayWithLength9 {  // Obv you can use a better name.
  private final int[] arr = new int[9];

  void set(int i, int value) { arr[i] = value; }
  int get(int i) { return arr[i]; }
}
```

Now, you know that if you've got an instance of this class, then the array has length 9, thus you don't need to check it.

So, you can now use `IntArrayWithLength9` instead of `int[]`.

Comment: Alternatively, the array could be exposed entirely through getter and be used normally without any impact to the rest of this code. So you still would pass around the carrier, but you'd do work on the array itself. Reduces the need for total rewrite. Breaks OOP a bit though.

Comment: @Compass alternatively just make the array visible.

Comment: @Ömer fine, that's your decision; but you then have to check (or assume) length.

Comment: Slow down, Andy, can't break every guideline in Java all at once :P