# Custom annotation on fuction parameter

Tags: kotlin

I want to make a function and annotate a parameter to be of a specific size, however following the official documentation is not clear on how one can do it.

The result is something similar to this:

```
fun getTypes(@size(250) data: ByteArray): Types {

}
```

Here `data` should be checked when received as parameter.

Comment: It's not clear what part of this you don't understand how to do. And do you want the size to be checked at run time when the function is called? Here's an answer mentioning a library that already has what you're describing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50134919/506796

Comment: I don't know of any way it could be checked at compile time. And if doing a run time check, it's probably easier to simply put `require(data.size == 250)` as the first line of your function, than it is to try using annotations, in my opinion.